# подсчет слов в поле ввода

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

сделал подсчет слов в поле ввода. считает правильно, но ошибка в том что когда начинаем удалять слова и доходит до последнего, то число остается на единице. в чем ошибка?

```js
function dayCount( val ){
    return {
        days              : val.match(/\S+/g).length
    }
}

var $div = $('#result');


$('#altField').on("propertychange change click keyup input paste", function() {
   
  var c = dayCount( this.value );
    
  $div.html(
      "<br>Words: "+  c.days
  );
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="altField" value="" >
    <div id="result"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bsg7ov8k/

Comment: Если метод match не находит совпадений, возвращается результат null. А у null нету свойства length, которые вы пытаетесь получить и функция падает с ошибкой. Смотрите консоль браузера в след. раз для текста ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас функция подсчета ошибку на применение регулярки к пустой строке кидает, можно сделать как то так

```
function dayCount( val ){
    try {
        return {
            days: val.match(/\S+/g).length
        }
    }
    catch (ex) {
        return {
            days:0
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, теперь все прекрасно работает, а то у меня из за того кода и другой плохо работал :)